# Using AWK to add a column to a TSV (tabbed separated file)

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I want to add a column to the beginning of a tabbed delimited file using awk, so a line like

```
col1    col2    col3
```

would end up like

```
345    col1    col2    col3
```

So far I have this

```
awk '{FS="  "; OFS="    "; print '345' $0;}'  file.tsv > output.tsv
```

but I end up with

```
345col1    col2    col3
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a comma after the '345'

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
awk '{print "345\t"$0}' file.tsv > output.tsv
```

Answer (score 0):

This awk should work:

```
awk '{FS=OFS="\t"; print '345', $0}' file
```

**EDIT:** Output on OSX with od to prove it works on OSX:

```
$> awk '{FS=OFS="\t"; print '345', $0}' file|od -c
0000000    3   4   5  \t   c   o   l   1  \t   c   o   l   2  \t   c   o
0000020    l   3  \n                                                    
0000023

$> uname -a
Darwin US143639.local 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386 i386
```

Comment: See edit section above to verify whether it works on OSX or not.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^/345\t/' file
```